# Django User matching query does not exist on foreign-key relation

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a system in Django by which users will login using a  phone number. Used `AbstractBaseUser` to use the number as user id. Now I am trying to create a foreign key relation of every transaction with the number. While I try to push a transaction, it says "User matching query does not exist". I am getting where I made mistake.

User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField("Phone number", max_length=100, unique=True, error_messages={
            'unique': ("number_existsssss"),
        })
    name = models.TextField("Name")
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField("Time-Date", auto_now=True)
    request_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="check"
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=('staff status'), default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=('active'), default=True)
```

Transaction Model:

```
class TransactionModel(models.Model):
    trxID = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, unique=True)
    User = models.ForeignKey(to=User, to_field="phone_number", related_name='transaction', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=1)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    pay_method = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    amountReceivedFrom = models.CharField(max_length=26, null=True)
    transactionStatus = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, default='False')
```

view for add-cash/b-kash request:

```
class BkashCashinView(APIView):
    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        HEADERS = {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
        if request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = BkashCashinSerializer(data = request.data)
            # serializer.is_valid()
            req = request.data
            trx_id = req.get('trxID')
            print(trx_id)
            phone_number = req.get('phone_number')
            recharge_amount = float(req.get('amount'))
            number_exists = User.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).exists()
            user = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
            print(user)
            current_user_data = User.objects.select_for_update().get(phone_number=phone_number)
            # current_user_data = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)

            with transaction.atomic():
                current_user_data.current_balance += recharge_amount
                current_user_data.save()

            print("phone numbe", req.get("amount"))
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

            current_balance = current_user_data.current_balance
            context = {
                "current_balance": current_balance,
                "status": "success"
            }
            serializer.save()
                # print(trx_id)

        return Response(context, headers = HEADERS)
```

I think I made some mistakes with the foreign key relation. The error shows:

```
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
user_signup.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
[04/Sep/2021 18:44:22] "POST /add-cash/b-kash HTTP/1.1" 500 20728
```

Comment: Please share the relevant view, of the view with url `/add-cash/b-kash/`.

Comment: Though I don't think the view will be relevant but added as you said